# Which command should I use to perform a search?

Tags: wpf, command

I'm working on a WPF app, using .NET 4.  I'm also trying to wrap my head about WPF Commands, and not always rely upon events, as I've done for  upteen years.  I'm trying to figure out which command to use.  I've come across a Search command, that that appears to be a part of the NavigationCommands, which doesn't make sense to me to use.  I've also found the Find command, but that's associated with Control-F, which makes me think its for finding a search in a document, like a Word document, so again, that doesn't look right to me.

Here's what I want to accomplish.  I will have some textboxes on the windows, for things like first name, last name, SSN and DOB.  I want to make it possible for the user to enter any or all of those, and then click on a button.  It then performs a search against our database for all records matching the parameters the user gave.  It will then put the returned results in a list box on the same window.

What WPF commmand do I use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No WPF Command will do this magically for you.**

You will have to write code for this.

Now there are two options...

1. If you are using `MVVM` pattern then you will have to use [DelegateCommands](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html&sa=U&ei=N7yfTvyeDZHLrQem6rTvAg&ved=0CBUQFjAD&sig2=bIRGEV2MBXGP2c-qqVhDNQ&usg=AFQjCNFrPbJDoe0FDTDMDpYcqplHQlmgyA).
2. Otherwise `RoutedComamnds` will do.

For RoutedCommands you could use a custom routed command OR use existing NavigationCommand.Search OR Find Commands, all you have to remember is to apply `CommandBindings`. Using `CommandBindings`, you have to provide an `OnExecuted` handler in which your logic will be put.

Now to extract what user have typed in the TextBoxes, you could bind the textboxes to the command using `CommandParameter`...

e.g.

Below is a simply code that displays "Hello World " when user types his / her name in the TetxBox and hits "Hit Me!" button, which has the command configured for it. The command also **disables** the button if user clears the textbox (i.e. invalid input).

**XAML**

```
    <Button Command="NavigationCommands.Search"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=UserNameTextBox}"
            Content="Hit Me!">
        <Button.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.Search"
                            Executed="OnSearchCommandExecuted"
                            CanExecute="CanSearchCommandExecute"/>
        </Button.CommandBindings>
    </Button>
    <TextBox Name="UserNameTextBox"
             Text="(Enter User Name)">            
    </TextBox>
```

**Code Behind ...**

```
    private void OnSearchCommandExecuted
       (object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World " + e.Parameter.ToString());
    }

    private void CanSearchCommandExecute
       (object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Parameter.ToString());
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the NavigationCommands.Search is generally meant to be used for someting like going from one WPF page to another via the navigation services, and passing to that second page some sort of search parameters?

Comment: See it can be used for anything... like in my example. :-) Its just that its behavior has to be defined by us but its keyboard gesture is predefined.

Comment: OK, I should also add that we're trying to implement this app using the MVVM design pattern.  So I guess that means we will have to use the DelegateCommands, or something similar.  But I'd like to know what the NavigationCommands.Search is meant to be used for?

Comment: Your assumption from first reply is correct about `NavigationCommands.Search`. Now as for `DelegateCommands` they can also be used for the same functionality. Its just that they would not add command bindings as their `Execute` and `CanExecute` delegates are specified while creating those commands itself in viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

A custom command should be used in this case.  You want to use command bindings and the RoutedCommand class.  Look [here in the example section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx).  This should give the basic information on how to make a simple custom command.